# Has SWIG for go become outdated since the removal of some C in Golang?

Tags: c++, go, swig, clang++, cgo

I've been trying to generate a Go wrapper for `open-vcdiff` so I took a look at SWIG for the first time with the following attempt:

godelta.swig

```
%module godelta
%include "include/godelta.hpp"
```

godelta.hpp

```
#include "config.h"
#include <assert.h>
#include <errno.h>
#ifdef WIN32
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <io.h>
#endif  // WIN32
#include <stdio.h>
#include "google/vcdecoder.h"
#include "google/vcencoder.h"
#include "google/jsonwriter.h"
#include "google/encodetable.h"
#include "unique_ptr.h" // auto_ptr, unique_ptr

#ifndef HAS_GLOBAL_STRING

#endif  // !HAS_GLOBAL_STRING

static const size_t kDefaultMaxTargetSize = 1 << 26;      // 64 MB

namespace godelta {

    class Godelta {
    public:
        Godelta();
        ~Godelta();

        bool Encode();
        bool Decode();
        bool DecodeAndCompare();

        int opt_buffersize;
        int opt_max_target_window_size;
        int opt_max_target_file_size;

    private:
        input file
        static bool FileSize(FILE* file, size_t* file_size);
        bool OpenFileForReading(const string& file_name,
                            const char* file_type,
                            FILE** file,
                            std::vector<char>* buffer);
        bool OpenDictionary();
        bool OpenInputFile() {
            return OpenFileForReading(input_file_name_,
                                  input_file_type_,
                                  &input_file_,
                                  &input_buffer_);
        }

        bool OpenOutputFile();
        bool OpenOutputFileForCompare() {
            return OpenFileForReading(output_file_name_,
                                  output_file_type_,
                                  &output_file_,
                                  &compare_buffer_);
        }

        bool ReadInput(size_t* bytes_read);
        bool WriteOutput(const string& output);
        bool CompareOutput(const string& output);

        std::vector<char> dictionary_;

        UNIQUE_PTR<open_vcdiff::HashedDictionary> hashed_dictionary_;

        const char* input_file_type_;
        const char* output_file_type_;

        string input_file_name_;
        string output_file_name_;

        FILE* input_file_;
        FILE* output_file_;

        std::vector<char> input_buffer_;
        std::vector<char> compare_buffer_;

        Godelta(const Godelta&);  // NOLINT
        void operator=(const Godelta&);
    };

} // namespace godelta
```

Swig works well, generating the files `godelta_wrap.cxx`, `godelta_gc.c` and `godelta.go`. The problem I'm facing now is that it's generating the includes:

```
#include "runtime.h"
#include "cgocall.h"
```

Resulting in the error:

```
godelta_gc.c:2:10: fatal error: 'runtime.h' file not found
```

I have looked everywhere for that file, even searched the Go repository on GitHub. I'm only finding what seems to be replacements of that file in Go.

By the way, my go version is:

```
go version go1.9 darwin/amd64
```

Clang:

```
Apple LLVM version 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.42)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.7.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

And SWIG:

```
SWIG Version 3.0.12
Compiled with g++ [x86_64-apple-darwin16.7.0]
Configured options: +pcre
```

Any insight on the subject will be highly appreciated, especially if it leads to me being able to run `go build` on the package without this error :-)

Comment: "Guthub", your one-stop source for free organs! ... I'll edit, but I wanted to preserve this beautiful typo for posterity ;)

Comment: Ouch! My bad. I mean no disrespect to Github :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like I was missing a flag on my Swig command. My original command looked like this:

```
swig -go -intgosize 64 godelta.swig
```

But as pointed out on the [issue](https://github.com/swig/swig/issues/1099) I eventually filed, I was supposed to include `-c++` and `-cgo` ending up with:

```
swig -c++ -go -cgo -intgosize 64 godelta.swig
```

It's working fine now :-)

Comment: how about the next? I have simple_wrap.cxx and simple.go file,  and try to compile simple.go with ‘’‘go tool compile simple.go’‘’
but reports simple.go:38:8: can't find import: "C"